# Solr inconsistent result count

Tags: solr, lucene

I have four nodes solrcloud setup version 4.10 and my collection has 4 shards, 2 replicas. My application provide the search ability with realtime data ingestion, both data ingestion and search processes runs in parallel.

Every day the data load is around 2~3MM records(insert/update operations) and total documents count is 80MM+.

The problem we are facing is that the solr returns very inconsistent records count during peak time of data ingestion.

Sample query:

```
for i in `seq 1 50`;
do
       curl 'http://localhost:8888/solr/OPTUM/select?q=*:*&wt=json&indent=true'|grep numFound|rev|cut -d'{' -f1 |rev
done
```

The response `numfound` variable shows sometime very less documents count then actually present in solr.

Please suggest if I need to make any configuration change to get consistent count.

Comment: Does this inconsistent `numFound` also reflect in the search result inconsistencies as well? Are you using autoCommit and autoSoftCommit configuration?

Comment: yes, the numfound is inconsistent in search result also. i have added commit configuration in post.<autoCommit> 
       <maxTime>30000</maxTime> 
       <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
     </autoCommit>

Comment: not sure if this would work in cloud, but does the admin call return the correct results? http://localhost:8888/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS

Comment: no, even UI doesn't return correct result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not yet found root cause of this problem but temporarily I did a work around to resolve this error.
I had been using solrj4.x softcommit method(`UpdateRequest.setCommitWithin( commitWithinMs )`) which I commented and used all commit strategy at solr end.

```
    <autoCommit>
            <maxTime>15000</maxTime>
            <openSearcher>false</openSearcher>
        </autoCommit>
<autoSoftCommit>
            <maxTime>2000</maxTime>
        </autoSoftCommit>
```

I am getting consistent result from solr but still I am not sure why solrj client side commit isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the problem is related how you query your distributed setup -- you said "my collection has 4 shards, 2 replicas" across 4 nodes ... your inconsistent results may be due to that you are redirected to a shard based on a load-balance algorithm -- so a different shard is used every time AND returns to you a different (subset) result set.

Read [Distributed Requests documentation here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Requests).

Try adding something like:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstarted/select?q=*:*&shards=nodehost1:7574/solr,nodehost2:8983/solr,nodehost3:8983/solr,nodehost4:8983/solr`

Comment: The query url i have posted in question is I used for testing, actually my application uses solrj and connectivity happens through zookeeper nodes, I am not able to supply shards details to solrj. I have tried to add shards to test url but it is not working.

Comment: The issue was with solrj softcommit which was causing inconsistency in results, I have posted the solution which worked for me,,thanks for help